# How to extract value from a column with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that was extracted using Pandas. The following column may contain one dictionary or more than one dictionary.

| Column B |
| --- |
| [{'url': 'mailto:Kim_Do@dmx.com', 'type': 0, 'id': 1021857, 'name': 'KIM Do', 'entryListId': -1}, {'url': 'mailto:Angel_Kong@dmx.com', 'type': 0, 'id': 1023306, 'name': 'Angel Kong', 'entryListId': -1}, {'url': 'mailto:Alex_Do@dmx.com', 'type': 0, 'id': 1023289, 'name': 'Alex Do', 'entryListId': -1} |
| [{'url': 'mailto:Ray_Chan@dmx.com', 'type': 0, 'id': 1021857, 'name': 'Ray Chan', 'entryListId': -1}, {'url': 'mailto:Paul_Jones@dmx.com', 'type': 0, 'id': 1023306, 'name': 'Paul Jones, 'entryListId': -1}] |
| nan |
| nan |
| [{'url': 'mailto:Ray_Chaudhry@dmx.com', 'type': 0, 'id': 1021857, 'name': 'Ray Chaudhry', 'entryListId': -1}] |

What I want back is just the names from the dictionary. So, the output should be as follows:

| Column B |
| --- |
| Kim Do, Angel Kong, Alex Do, Fred Tome |
| Ray Chan, Paul Jones |
| nan |
| nan |
| Ray Chaudhry |

How can I achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['New'] = df['Column B'].explode().str['name'].dropna().groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

Output (New column only):

```
0    KIM Do, Angel Kong, Alex Do
1           Ray Chan, Paul Jones
2                            NaN
3                            NaN
4                   Ray Chaudhry
```

Comment: Thank you mozway. I am getting this error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: can you provide a reproducible input as `DataFrame` constructor?

Comment: Hi @mozway, I am not sure you mean as I am new to pythons and pandas. Do you mean df = pd.DataFrame(rows). Thanks you

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check out the screenshot]

Use this function:

```
def extract_names(list_data):
    row_names = []
    for n in range(len(list_data)):
        row_names.append(list_data[n]['name'])
    return row_names

store_names = []
col = 0 #column name
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
#     print(idx)
#     print(row[col])
    store_names.append(extract_names(row[col]))
#     print('--')
```

Now you can store the list as parameter of your choice:

```
df['Names'] = store_names
```